# Pass a date as a get request on postman however i can't find data from database in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, postman, get-request

I like to get my value when I pass the date in get a request.
But when I pass [http://127.0.0.1:8000/api//news/search/"2022-05-10"](http://127.0.0.1:8000/api//news/search/%222022-05-10%22)

date "2022-05-10" was not found but I entered the value of this date in the database.

Here is a screenshot of my Postman request:

[image]

Here is the controller:

```
public function getNewsDate($dates) {
    $news = News::where('date', $dates)->get();
    if ($news) {
        return response()->json($news, 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json('News not found', 404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your route in `api.php` it should be as:

```
Route::get('/news/search/{dates}', [NewsController::class, 'getNewsDate']);
```

You have two slashes after `api` by the way)

```
api//news/search
```

remove one of them.

Comment: I did it but from now not show the expected data that I want, it is empty.

Comment: There may not any record with this date in your news table. You have to remove commas as well. It should be like `api/news/search/2022-05-10`.